# Redirect for HTTP POST does not work in SvelteKit

Tags: redirect, fetch-api, sveltekit, http-status-code-303

In SvelteKit I want to handle a post request and redirect to a route on success. This should be possible by sending a status code of 303 and the location header - as in the [SvelteKit docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-post-put-patch-delete). Unfortunately, it does not work. In the Dev tools you see the 303 response, but the redirect is not handled. Of course, there are workarounds (for example, a redirect on the client, or directly post to the desired page), but I would like to know why this error happens.

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-z9rs2c

**index.svelte**

```
 <script>
   function submit() {
     fetch("/endpoint", {method: "POST"});
   }
 </script>

 <button on:click={submit}>Click me</button>
```

**endpoint.js**

```
export function post() {
    console.log('got post request at endpoint');
    return {
        status: 303,
        headers: {
            location: '/success'
        }
    };
 }
```

**success.svelte**

```
 <h2>Success</h2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP POST redirect is handled by web browsers only if you are using native `<form method=POST>` HTML construct.

You are using `fetch()` API, which is very different. Thus you need to handle the redirect yourself.

You can do this by extracting `location` from the `fetch()` response headers and then calling manually `goto()` from [$app/navigation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation).

Answer (score 0):

Future reference this can be handled with 307/308 status code response and Location header. As most browsers implemented 301/302 to change to get request 307/308 we're needed to rectify and not change request type/mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).